# React Native Notifee: Notifications not displaying in the background, work in the foreground, and the killed state

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobile, push-notification, notifications

I am developing Mobile App with React Native and using `Notifee` with `Firebase` to send push notifications. I tried these codes on the Android. Notifications are displayed when the app is in the foreground and killed state. But it doesn't display when the app is in the background. I see the notifications come to devices with console.log but the `DisplayNotificationData` function doesn't work until I open the app.

- Set `setBackgroundMessageHandler` in  `....Home\index.js`
- I send the `only data` notifications from Firebase as a solution for the notifications display twice in the killed state.
- I checked and removed the `Battery Optimization` and the `Power Management` restrictions.

```
// ....Home\index.js
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background in index.js!', remoteMessage);

  // DisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
  DisplayNotificationData(remoteMessage);
}
```

Here is the displaying notifications function with Notifee

```
// android\app\src\utils\push_notification_helper.js
export async function DisplayNotificationData(remoteMessage) {
  // Required for iOS
  // See https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/permissions
  await notifee.requestPermission();

  // Create a channel for android
  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id: 'important',
    name: 'Important Notifications',
    importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
  });

  // Access custom data
  const {title, body} = remoteMessage.data;

  // Display a notification using notifee
  await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: title,
    body: body,
    android: {
      channelId: channelId,
    },
  });

  console.log('DisplayNotificationData is worked!');
}
```

Here is the checking the restrictions:

```
// android\app\src\utils\push_notification_helper.js
// the function that check the Battery Optimization Enabled and it pops up turn off message.
export async function requestbatteryOptimizationTurnOff() {
  // 1. checks if battery optimization is enabled
  const batteryOptimizationEnabled =
    await notifee.isBatteryOptimizationEnabled();
  if (batteryOptimizationEnabled) {
    // 2. ask your users to disable the feature
    Alert.alert(
      'Restrictions Detected',
      'To ensure notifications are delivered, please disable battery optimization for the app.',
      [
        // 3. launch intent to navigate the user to the appropriate screen
        {
          text: 'OK, open settings',
          onPress: async () => await notifee.openBatteryOptimizationSettings(),
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  } else {
    console.log("Restrictions aren't detected for Battery Optimization");
  }
}

export async function requestPowerManagerSettingsTurnOff() {
  // 1. get info on the device and the Power Manager settings
  const powerManagerInfo = await notifee.getPowerManagerInfo();
  if (powerManagerInfo.activity) {
    // 2. ask your users to adjust their settings
    Alert.alert(
      'Restrictions Detected',
      'To ensure notifications are delivered, please adjust your settings to prevent the app from being killed',
      [
        // 3. launch intent to navigate the user to the appropriate screen
        {
          text: 'OK, open settings',
          onPress: async () => await notifee.openPowerManagerSettings(),
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  } else {
    console.log("Restrictions aren't detected for Power Managment.");
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Also tried this code in `index.js`

```
messaging().getInitialNotification(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('notification on getInitialNotification......', remoteMessage);
  // DisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
  DisplayNotificationData(remoteMessage);
});
```

And, tried this code to receive background notifications.

```
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({type, detail}) => {
  const {notification, pressAction} = detail;
  console.log('Message handled in the notifee onBackgroundEvent! in index.js');

  DisplayNotificationData(notification);

  if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && pressAction.id === 'mark-as-read') {
    // Update external API
    // await fetch(`https://my-api.com/chat/${notification.data.chatId}/read`, {
    //   method: 'POST',
    // });
    // Remove the notification
    await notifee.cancelNotification(notification.id);
  }
});
```